# Please suggest some resource to learn medical chinese vocabulary

Tags: resources, terminology

the words which the patients will usually use to describe their symptoms and vocabulary which the doctor might use to describe the common scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I find a PDF. Please enjoy!

- Chinese-English Regularly Used Medical Terms
- Chinese-English Terms for Body Parts and Organs

https://iconproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Chinese_English_Regularly_Used_Medical_Terms.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I want to study lists of words in some category, I get ChatGPT to list 100 of them.  In this case [like this](https://chat.openai.com/share/84ebe564-0884-40cc-b163-6b8676adc955), which gives:

> 头痛, 腹痛, 恶心, 呕吐, 疲劳, 发热, 寒战, 流感, 咳嗽, 喉咙痛, 流感, 流感症状, 疼痛, 不适, 失眠, 头晕, 失衡, 呼吸困难, 胸痛, 心悸, 血压升高, 血糖升高, 食欲减退, 体重下降, 便秘, 腹泻, 尿频, 尿急, 尿痛, 皮疹, 发疹, 红肿, 肿胀, 关节痛, 肌肉疼痛, 头皮屑, 脱发, 呼吸急促, 胸闷, 咳痰, 胸部不适, 眼干, 眼痛, 视力模糊, 耳鸣, 听力下降, 鼻塞, 流鼻涕, 嗓子痛, 声音嘶哑, 皮肤瘙痒, 看不清楚, 闻不到味道, 嗓子痒, 腰痛, 腿痛, 手脚发麻, 肚子疼, 肚子胀, 恶心呕吐, 头昏脑胀, 头昏眼花, 冷汗淋漓, 手脚冰凉, 胸口闷痛, 脚肿, 手指发紫, 脚趾发紫, 脚趾发麻。

Then I flick through the list and study (using a diverse collection of resources: Google, dictionaries, example sentences, Google image search, etc.) whichever words I find important.  Usually some of the vocabulary ChatGPT gives is too easy, and some is rather unnatural, so I don't study them all.

If you chat with it, you can ask for simpler words, or words more related to certain parts of the body.  ChatGPT will give better responses if you give it an idea of which words you think are easy and which are hard, or if you give it some words you already know and ask for medical words at a similar level.

Since we live in the future, we can also roleplay with ChatGPT and learn words in context.  [Here](https://chat.openai.com/share/a5b0da4b-125b-42cc-9501-88c53cb49ffa), I told ChatGPT to pretend that I'm a doctor, and it's my patient.  ChatGPT came in my office saying it has a headache and itchy throat, thinking it could have a cold, and asked me what it should do.  As you can see, it can take a little while to get the hang of it, but it's not too bad.

I've done other roleplaying like this, e.g., getting ChatGPT to pretend it's a medical researcher and I'm conducting an interview.  You could probably ask it to be a surgeon, or a med student, etc.